# Python lazy boolean evaluation gone wrong?

Tags: python

Why this works:

```
s = 'xyz'
i = 0     
while i < len(s) and s[i] not in 'aeiou':
        print(s[i])
        i += 1
```

> ```
> x
> y
> z
> ```

... but this does not?

```
s = 'xyz'
i = 0 
while s[i] not in 'aeiou' and i < len(s):
    print(s[i])
    i += 1
```

> ```
> x
> y
> z
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#135>", line 1, in <module>
>     while s[i] not in 'aeiou' and i <= len(s):
> IndexError: string index out of range
> ```

I'm confused, what am I missing here?

Comment: In `s[i] not in 'aeiou' and i < len(s)`, `s[i]` is evalued first, thus the error.

Comment: Actually the title should read "Lazy evaluation working exactely as expected and documented".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To evaluate

```
s[i] not in 'aeiou' and i < len(s)
```

*first* `s[i]` is evaluated. For `i = 3` this throws an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 1):

`and` is a binary boolean operator that operates by first checking its left operand's conditional value and then checking its right operand's conditional value if and only if the left operand evaluates to True. You are going out of bounds with your second code because you are not checking to first see if `i` is within the range of the length of your string `s`.

When you do something like:

`while i < len(s) and s[i] not in 'aeiou':`

The `and` operator will short-circuit and it will not check to see if `s[i]` is not in 'aeiou' if `i` itself is out of the range of the string. Thus, you are safe from out-of-bounds array access on the string! If you flip the order of the conditions you will check to see if `s[i]` is in 'aeiou' without checking first to see if 'i' is in range.

Alternatively if you check it like this:

`while s[i] not in 'aeiou' and i < len(s):`

If and only if, the first condition evaluates to true, will it check the second condition `i < len(s)`. In Python these conditions are evaluated in order and it's important to remember that both `and` and `or` check conditions sequentially from left to right and they also short-circuit (if the truth value can be determined from the truth value of the first condition, the second is not evaluated at all.)

Answer (score 0):

because in the second case,

checking of i's index is done after accessing s[i]

thus, even if i = 3,

it will try to access s[3] first and then check that i > 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
while s[i] not in 'aeiou' and i < len(s):
```

you're accessing `s[i]` *before* checking if `i` is within the range.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions are evaluated in order.  When you reverse the order of the conditions you cause different code to execute.  In this particular instance, that causes an exception when you access a non-existent index in your string.  That never happens in the other result, because the condition "short circuits" when the first False is encountered.